# Doing statitstics on a dataframe column containg several 'subgroups' delimited by zeros

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which contains the following data in one column. The zeros act as delimiters / separators, the non-zero values are values for a 'sub-group'. I want to calculate some statistics (i.e. len (duration), mean) for each of the group and save it as a new dataframe:

```
ts = pd.Series([0,1,2,0,0,0,5,4,7,0], pd.date_range("2020-12-27", periods=10))
ts
Out[131]: 
    2020-12-27    0
    2020-12-28    1
    2020-12-29    2
    2020-12-30    0
    2020-12-31    0
    2021-01-01    0
    2021-01-02    5
    2021-01-03    4
    2021-01-04    7
    2021-01-05    0
```

The result I would like to have is this:

```
    Beginning   Duration  Mean
    2020-12-28  2         1.5
    2020-01-02  3         5.33
```

I have actually no clue where and how I should start! Any suggestions?

Thanks to answers which made me understand a bit more of python. I tried to expand the proposal from anky to return the minimum and the index of the minimum:

```
    out = ts.groupby(ts.eq(0).cumsum().loc[ts.ne(0)]).agg(
    Beginning = lambda x: x.index[0],Duration="count", Mean="mean",
    Minimum='min', MinIdx='idxmin').reset_index(drop=True)

       Beginning  Duration      Mean  Minimum     MinIdx
    0 2020-12-28         2  1.500000        1 2020-12-28
    1 2021-01-02         3  5.333333        4 2021-01-03
```

But instead of the index (as Date) I would like to have the position as integer, i.e. the first minimum was reached 0 days after the beginning, the second minimum was reached 1 day (or more generally 1 time increment) after the beginning. I tried to use get_loc but got only error-messages.
Any further suggestions?

Comment: is the second mean meant to be 6? (5+4+7) / 3 = 5.33

Comment: Sure, 5.33 is of course correct.

Answer (score 1):

```py
In [33]: ts
Out[33]:
2020-12-27    0
2020-12-28    1
2020-12-29    2
2020-12-30    0
2020-12-31    0
2021-01-01    0
2021-01-02    5
2021-01-03    4
2021-01-04    7
2021-01-05    0
Freq: D, dtype: int64

In [34]: (   
    ts
    .reset_index(name='val')
    .assign(group=ts.eq(0).cumsum().tolist())
    .query('val != 0')
    .groupby('group')
    .agg({'index': 'first', 'val': ['count', 'mean']})
    .droplevel(0, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
)

Out[34]:
       first  count      mean
0 2020-12-28      2  1.500000
1 2021-01-02      3  5.333333
```

Answer (score 1):

here is another way of achieving your goal using a mask and groupby with named aggregation:

```
out = ts.groupby(ts.eq(0).cumsum().loc[ts.ne(0)]).agg(
Beginning = lambda x: x.index[0],Duration="count",Mean="mean").reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
print(out)

   Beginning  Duration      Mean
0 2020-12-28         2  1.500000
1 2021-01-02         3  5.333333
```

Comment: **Note** This assumes that the datetime index is already sorted, if not, sorting of the index of the series is necessary first

Comment: Thanks. I tried to expand the proposal  to return the minimum and the index of the minimum:

        out = ts.groupby(ts.eq(0).cumsum().loc[ts.ne(0)]).agg(
        Beginning = lambda x: x.index[0],Duration="count", Mean="mean",
        Minimum='min', MinIdx='idxmin').reset_index(drop=True)

           Beginning  Duration      Mean  Minimum     MinIdx
        0 2020-12-28         2  1.500000        1 2020-12-28
        1 2021-01-02         3  5.333333        4 2021-01-03

Comment: But instead of the index I would like to have the position as integer, i.e. the second minimum was reached 1 day (or more generally 1 time increment) after the beginning.